# How much goes to my local shelter?

Tags: shelter, humane-society, fundraising

I keep seeing TV and News paper ads for the [ASPCA](http://www.aspca.org/) and [The Humane Society of the United States](http://www.humanesociety.org/), if I donate money to either of these what percentage goes to my local shelter?

Comment: I think this question would be improved if it asked what else they spend their money on.

Comment: Shelters across the country vary in size and activity, so I'd guess this question is rather difficult to answer for one shelter only. Somewhat easier perhaps, if question was "what percentage of total amount donated actually goes to shelters?"

Comment: Created as http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1827/where-does-the-money-go as seperate question.  I think they should be seperate.  But will understand if this is deleted as a dupe of the other.

Comment: I think based on the answers you're bound to get on the other question, this would be a dupe.

Comment: There is an answer on the other question.  It does not directly address local shelters, but I am pretty sure the answer is 0%

Comment: This is pretty complex and localized. For example, just looking at the ASPCA, they run several programs directly in NYC, so a NYC shelter would recieve more benefits from their spay/neuter program than one in LA or elsewhere. In addition, they ask local shelters to apply for grants, so without knowing if your local shelter applied for a grant, how much, was it approved, it's impossible to know how much your local shelter got ($17 million was granted, but that includes equine rescues, not just dog/cat shelters).