# How is funding donated to the ASPCA and Humane Society animal charities applied?

Tags: humane-society, fundraising

I keep seeing TV and News paper ads for the [ASPCA](http://www.aspca.org/) and [The Humane Society of the United States](http://www.humanesociety.org/).  If I donate money to either organization, where does the money go?

Comment: Note that the ASPCA, despite its name, is just another regional SPCA -- and iny opinion ***not*** one if the best. Don't limit your investigation to these two; check out others before deciding where your money will do the most good. There are several websites which gather the sort of budgeting/effectiveness summary you are looking for and can help you find good candidate charities.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **ASPCA** distributes its income in the following ways:

> - Program Expenses 58.4%
> - Administrative Expenses 5.2%
> - Fundraising Expenses 36.2%

[Charity Navigator Rating - ASPCA](http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm?bay=search.summary&orgid=3286)

Program Expenses fund the charity to do its mission work. The ASPCA reports that it engages in many [programs and services](http://www.aspca.org/about-us/programs-and-services), including:

> - Anti-Cruelty Group
>
>   - Anti-Cruelty Behavior Team
>   - Cruelty Intervention Advocacy Program
>   - Field Investigations and Response
>   - ASPCA Forensic Services
>   - Legal Advocacy
>   - Strategy and Campaigns
> - Animal Health Services
>
>   - Animal Poison Control Center
>   - ASPCA Animal Hospital
>   - Spay/Neuter Operations: Mobile and Stationary Clinics
> - Community Outreach
>
>   - ASPCA Onyx and Breezy Shefts Adoption Center
>   - Community Initiatives
>   - ProLearning
>   - Shelter Research and Development
>   - Grants
> - Government Relations

---

The **Humane Society of the United States** distributes its income in the following ways:

> - Program Expenses 78.6%
> - Administrative Expenses 3.4%
> - Fundraising Expenses 17.9%

[Charity Navigator Rating - The Humane Society of the United States](http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm?bay=search.summary&orgid=3848)

The [2012 HSUS Accomplishments](http://www.humanesociety.org/about/overview/2012_accomplishments.html) include:

> - Provided Care for 100,000+ Animals, Including Pets Affected by    Hurricane Sandy
> - Spared 110 Chimps from Use as Research Subjects
> - Banned Four Giant Snake Species as Pets Banned New Ownership of Dangerous Wild Animals in Ohio
> - Encouraged Amazon.com to Stop Selling Whale and Dolphin Meat
> - Banned Hound Hunting of Bears and Bobcats in California
> - Helped Land a Historic Judgment Against a Slaughter Plant
> - Defended a Law Against Selling Foie Gras from Force-Fed Ducks
> - Garnered Support from the Courts Across the Country
> - Expanded the Pets for Life Program to the West Coast
> - Led an Investigation that Helped Prosecute a “Big Lick” Horse Trainer
> - Convinced Corporations to Get Out of the Gestation Crate Business
> - Won Awards, Made News and Produced Videos